# How to distinguish a function is client script or server script

Tags: google-app-maker

Thanks for you read my question.
I know the define of Client script and Server script.

[Client script]
Contains JavaScript that the browser’s JavaScript engine runs.

[Server script]
Contains JavaScript that a JavaScript engine on the App Maker server runs.

But I have no idea to know a function will run on browser’s JavaScript engine or on App Maker server.

Are there some effective and obvious methods to distinguish a function is client script or server script?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For AM specifically, when adding a new script file it will let you choose Client or Server script and then that particular script file will run on client or server. Since AM runs via Google Apps Script any interaction where you specifically call a server function it needs to be initiated from the client by calling google.scripts.run(YourServerFunction()). You are able to have the same function name in a server script and client script, however you cannot have two functions called the same on either server or client scripts. All model events run on the server. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry.
I don't describe it clearly.

I know it will let me choose Client or Server script when adding a new script.
But how to distinguish my new script which should be a Client script or Server script.

Comment: In that case I would say to decide based on either how secure your script operation needs to be or if your script needs to work on records currently loaded in the client or a larger set of records. Server scripts are generally more secure compared to client scripts, so therefore if only certain roles or individuals are allowed to perform the script then I would select a server script. Also, if your datasource only loads 25 records but you need to perform an operation on all records from a model then also choose server script.

Comment: Hi Markus
Thanks a lot.